# Execute batch application in background using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application with a Task Scheduler based on [this implementation](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/).
Basically, during development in Eclipse, I execute the following maven goal:

```
mvn clean install exec:java
```

to execute the batch application. The above command executes my MainApp class which has a *static main* class that loads the Application context file and from there, Spring takes control. During development, this is not a problem since I need to see the logs in the console. But during integration in my Jenkins server I am encountering a problem with this setup.

In Jenkins, when I try to build the application using the above goal, the build never finishes because it holds on to the console. I need the build to finish so that the downstream projects are also built. My question is, how do I tell Jenkins to ignore the console and proceed to the next build process? In short I want to start the batch application on the background without it holding on to the console so that my build can continue.

What I have tried so far:

I tried changing the goals such that `exec:java` will be called as a *Post Step*. Still it does not work. What are other methods in which to perform this?

Comment: May be this blog post can give some ideas, as it seems to have the same initial problem: http://giallone.blogspot.com/2013/06/maven-start-external-process-without.html?_sm_au_=i6H5QZVnt1Qk1JMR ?